# What are the fundamental difference between the Server 2008 editions and Windows 7 Editions?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008

I was wondering what the differences between the different flavours of Server 2008 (Enterprise, Business, etc) and Windows 7 (Home, Premium, Business, Ultimate, etc). Apart from Cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complementary server version to Windows 7 is Windows Server 2008 R2.  It has various **[server roles](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx)** and excludes desktop applications and drivers.

Comment: Well, that table seems to do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @tombull89: You're welcome.  Here's another one for Windows 7 editions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart

Comment: I had found that particular table and was wondering if there was anything along the lines of that on the MS site, a la what you provided for me for Server 2008 Comparison. Thanks, though.

Comment: @tombull89: I thought that table was more informative than the MS one, which leaves out Starter, Home Basic and Enterprise.  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/compare